# Thumbnail limit max ''6'' images

Tags: php, drupal-7, drupal-modules, break

I'm using Drupal 7 and create a module for my content thumbnail images frontpage display. Working this:

```
    if(count($p_detail->field_slide) > 0){
        $output .= '<div class="right">';
        $output .= '<ul class="thumbs">';
        $i=1;
        foreach($p_detail->field_slide['und'] as $thumb):
            $img_path = $thumb['uri'];
            $img_url = image_style_url('tmb_240x117', $img_path);
            $img_file = '<img src="'.$img_url.'" alt="'.$p_detail->title.'" />';


            $output .= '<li>
                            <a href="'.$p_url.'">
                                '.$img_file.'
                                <div class="shadow"></div>        
                                <div class="hoverimg"></div>
                             </a>
                            <div class="img_no">0'.$i.'</div>
                        </li>';
            $i++;
        endforeach;
        $output .= '</ul>';
        $output .= '</div>';
    }
```

This codes is working. But i want show max thumbnails 6 images. For example, have got 20 images, show only first 6 images. If 2 images, only thumbnails 2 images. How can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just add this line below your foreach:

```
foreach($p_detail->field_slide['und'] as $thumb):
  if($i>6) { break; }
  $img_path = $thumb['uri'];
```

This will just end the foreach loop after 6 images has been printed.